# Android Vitals : no data available for one of my apps

Tags: java, android, analytics, developer-console

I have no data available in Android Vitals for one of my apps (the other apps are ok) and I don't understand why.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: How active are the various apps? is the usage similar across this app and the others? We have about 20 apps (for the Kiwix project) and only get Android Vitals data for the popular apps, we've a few niche apps with low volumes of users and we get minimal data for those.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/index.html

> Note: The data is collected from Android devices whose users have opted-in to automatically share usage and diagnostics data. To protect user privacy, we show metrics in the dashboard only if we have been able to collect enough data to generate anonymized reports. For more information on how the data is collected, see the Play Console Help Center.

Comment: I have almost 2000 active users of my app and still no data available in Android Vitals section. I don't believe nobody has opted-in to share data from so many users